# Store old value of reference type

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I am creating custom designer for my `MainTabControl` (extended `TabControl`). In `OnAddTab` method I am changing `TabPageCollection` by adding a new tab to it.

How could I provide oldValue for `RaiseComponentChanged`? `TabPageCollection` is a **reference type**.

PS. I know about deep copy, but looking for better solution.

Docs: 
[TabPageCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection?view=netframework-4.8.1)

[RaiseComponentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.raisecomponentchanged?view=netframework-4.8.1)

```cs
public class MainTabControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    DesignerVerbCollection _verbs;
    IDesignerHost _designerHost;

    //...

    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if(_verbs == null)
            {
                _verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection()
                {
                    new DesignerVerb("Add Tab", new EventHandler(OnAddTab)),
                    new DesignerVerb("Remove Tab", new EventHandler(OnRemoveTab))
                };

                MainTabControl mainTabControl = Control as MainTabControl;
                if (mainTabControl != null)
                {
                    if (mainTabControl.TabPages.Count == 0) _verbs[1].Enabled = false;

                    else _verbs[1].Enabled = true;
                }
            }

            return _verbs;
        }
    }

    public void OnAddTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainTabControl parentControl = Control as MainTabControl;
        MainTabControl.TabPageCollection oldTabs = parentControl.TabPages;

        DesignerTransaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = _designerHost.CreateTransaction("Add Tab");

            RaiseComponentChanging(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(parentControl)["TabPages"]);

            MainTabPage newPage = (MainTabPage)_designerHost.CreateComponent(typeof(MainTabPage));
            newPage.Text = newPage.Name;
            parentControl.TabPages.Add(newPage);
            parentControl.SelectedTab = newPage;

            RaiseComponentChanged(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(parentControl)["TabPages"], oldTabs, parentControl.TabPages);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception occured during adding the tab");
            transaction?.Cancel();
        }

    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply call the method as `RaiseComponentChanged([MemberDescriptor], null, null)`? This is what the default designer does (you know what member has changed) -- BTW, the `TabControlDesigner` derives from `ParentControlDesigner`, not `ControlDesigner` (because of `CanParent` - which relates to both the underlying `Control` and the `ControlDesigner` - instead of `CanBeParented`, `InvokeCreateTool()` etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I applied both advices, which solve the problem.